# OutOfMemoryException in Assembly.LoadFile

Tags: vb.net, com, c++-cli, out-of-memory, system.reflection

I'm quite stumped on this one. Sometimes, when I call `Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("path to my dll")` it will throw an `OutOfMemoryException`.

The StackTrace just shows:

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile(String path, Evidence evidence)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String path)
```

And there is no `InnerException` to check for more detailed exception information.

However, only through COM it seems.

Let me explain:

My application can be started as a regular old exe, or through Excel via COM interface (`CreateObject("blahblahblah")`)

Upon initializing one of my GUI classes, it will statically load all my engine DLLs as well (my application has an engine and a GUI)

There are a total of 6 engine DLLs - the statically loaded assembly code is in VB.NET and looks somewhat like this:

```
Private Shared dllPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) & System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
Private Shared ReadOnly engineDLL1 As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath + "engineDLL1_name.dll")
...
Private Shared ReadOnly engineDLL6 As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath + "engineDLL6_name.dll")
```

The engine DLLs I am trying to load by the way are mixed assemblies (contain native and managed C++) - not sure if that matters.

Anyways, using procexp, I noticed opening my application the standard way, all these statically loaded DLLs all load fine. However, if I initialize this class through COM (via Excel, `CreateObject("ProgID of the class with the code above")`), it will throw the `OutOfMemoryException` at around engineDLL4.

If anyone can offer any insights, that would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Try to use [VMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd535533.aspx) with the "Options > Show Free and Unusable Regions" on.  Try to figure out if you don't have enough contiguous space to hold .NET's memory regions and any of the loaded assemblies.  You can also try to use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) by opening your application and using "Profile > Start Profiling..." and see if there are library load errors.

Comment: There is very little reason to assume the CLR is lying to you, particularly given that you are using such an inappropriate way to load the assembly.  Assembly.LoadFile() was very poorly named, they should have picked LoadDangerously().  Always use LoadFrom() so you cannot load the same assembly more than once.

Comment: @HansPassant - Using LoadFrom still throws the OutOfMemoryException

Comment: What is the capacity of your machine's memory (aka RAM)? I had this problem earlier when I had lower memory (i.e 2GB) But since I upgraded I didn't found the issue till now.